# How can I make an object using another object in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, code-reuse

I am defining the characteristics of a Dog class which contains instance data defining their name and age, making constructors for this data, setter-getter methods, etc. I also have a method which returns the value of "dog years" (aka, seven years times a human year that passes for their equivalent age). I have a driver class, Kennel, which main method instantiates and updates these Dog objects, and prints them out.

In the Kennel class, one of my last statements you can see a comment that says ""INQUIRE AT SOME POINT".
I.e: `//Dog dog3 = dog2.setName("Krypto");`
In the comment, I have tried to make a new Dog object called "Kryto" while assigning the rest of  the dog2 object's data to it via a setName method. In other words, I want my dog3 object to have all of dog2's characteristics with the exception of the name.

What would be the way to accomplish this? I understand that I can't use an object as a parameter, right?

Here's my code for the two classes below:

```
Kennel (Driver):

    public class Kennel {
    //instance data
    int age;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //dog objects
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Bear", 3);
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Bella", 7);
        
        //calling the method required to calculate the dog's human years, so that when I print these objects out, they actually have their traits
        //(that being, their "dogman" age.
        dog1.calcDogmanYears();
        dog2.calcDogmanYears();
        
        //output
        System.out.println(dog1);
        System.out.println(dog2);
        dog2.setName("Krypto");
        //Dog dog3 = dog2.setName("Krypto"); //INQUIRE AT SOME POINT
        System.out.println(dog2);

    }

}
```

Dog:

```
public class Dog {
    //instance data
    String name;
    int age;
    
    //constructor (normal) to allow objects to have values by default (i.e. no requirement of forcing parameters down the methods from the driver class)
    public Dog()    {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
        return;
    }
    
    //constructor, keep in mind for future reference, that I used different variables to allow the constructor to be overloaded in a driver class to
    //follow Chapter 4's constructor Java syntax. We could've overloaded the constructor with formal parameters of the same name as the instance data
    //with the "this.(insert variable here)" modifier. I did this for shits and giggles.
    public Dog(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        return;
    }
    
    //method to convert dog to human years
    public int calcDogmanYears() {
        age = age * 7;
        return age;
    }
        
    //setters and getters for name
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    //mutators and accessors for age}
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String result = "The name of the dog is " + name + ", and their age is " + age + " years old.";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `setName` is a `void` method, as is the convention for setters, it doesn't return *anything* much less a new `Dog` instance.

Comment: Are you saying essentially that in order to create a new object out of the characteristics of an old one, I would need to use a method that returns a value? Why can't I just use a mutator method?

Comment: Realise that you're asking *"why can't I use a mutator method to do something different to mutating?"* Because it wouldn't be a mutator method any more? It **doesn't return anything**, so `Dog dog3 = dog2.setName("Krypto");` makes no sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define a new method in `Dog` class:

```
public Dog createTheSameAgeDog(String name) {
    return new Dog(name, this.age);
}
```

Then call it:

```
Dog dog3 = dog2.createTheSameAgeDog("Krypto"); // creates the Dog (age 7, name "Krypto")
```

Comment: Huh okay, I do have another question. How come you used the "this" function (am I even using the right term here?) on the "age" variable, and not the name variable? Wouldn't "this" in this case call to the age in the instance data of the class, and not the method? There are two "name" variables declared with this code, one was a formal argument to overload the method and one in the instance data of the class. Wouldn't the compiler get confused on "name" and not "age"?

Comment: `this` is a reference to an object on which the method is invoked. For example, if you call **dog2**`.createTheSameAgeDog("Krypto");` then `this` reference inside the method `createTheSameAgeDog` equals to `dog2`. The method parameter `name` will not conflict with the field `name` as soon as  method parameter "shadows" the field.

Comment: Okay, that seems to make sense, because we are already cramming a name variable "Krypto" down the createTheSameAgeDog method, and with age we're telling the computer that the age we're using for the new dog3 object (i.e. THIS age) would be dog2 objects age, a la, calling back to the class to reference the established dog2 object age, right?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping clarify this for me, nkrivenko! Couldn't've done it better without ya! Much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure! If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark :)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to make the `Dog` class cloneable.  Clone the original, then set the `name` appropriately.

```
Dog dog3 = dog2.clone();
dog3.setName("Krypto");
```

Kennel (Driver) class:

```
public class Kennel {
    //instance data
    int age;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        //dog objects
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Bear", 3);
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Bella", 7);
        
        //calling the method required to calculate the dog's human years, so that when I print these objects out, they actually have their traits
        //(that being, their "dogman" age.
        dog1.calcDogmanYears();
        dog2.calcDogmanYears();
        
        //output
        System.out.println(dog1);
        System.out.println(dog2);
        dog2.setName("Krypto");
        Dog dog3 = dog2.clone();
        dog3.setName("Krypto"); //INQUIRE AT SOME POINT
        System.out.println(dog2);

    }

}
```

Updated Dog class:

```
public class Dog implements Cloneable {
    //instance data
    String name;
    int age;
    
    //constructor (normal) to allow objects to have values by default (i.e. no requirement of forcing parameters down the methods from the driver class)
    public Dog()    {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
    }
    // Overriding clone() method of Object class
    public Dog clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{  
    return (Dog) super.clone();  
    }
    
    public Dog(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    //method to convert dog to human years
    public int calcDogmanYears() {
        age = age * 7;
        return age;
    }
        
    //setters and getters for name
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    //mutators and accessors for age}
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String result = "The name of the dog is " + name + ", and their age is " + age + " years old.";
        return result;
    }
}
```

**output:**

> The name of the dog is Bear, and their age is 21 years old.
> The name of the dog is Bella, and their age is 49 years old.
> The name of the dog is Krypto, and their age is 49 years old.

Comment: Holy donk, I didn't know about the clone method! This was what I was more along the lines of what I was looking for! Glad that this was the second answer, though. Funny how you learn things when it doesn't work out right then and there. Thanks geocode!